# sort an array of entities symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have an array of entities and I want to sort it depending on one attribute of this entity. 
I saw that function like sort() is defined in php but I want to add the element based on which  will be done the comparison. any ideas???

```
$qb->select('a')
     ->from('TelnOperatorBundle:Subnumber', 'a')
     ->where('a.numberrange = :id')
     ->setParameter('id', $id);

 //$entites=$qb->getQuery()
             // ->getResult();
 $entites = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
asort($entites);
//var_dump($entites);


foreach($entites as $entite)
{
  //$entite est une instance d'Article pour notre exemple
   echo($entite->getId());
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you just add an orderBy() to your query?

Comment: @AhmedSiouani I tried the orderBy and it works for an integer attribute but I want to make the sort on a string attribute. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You don't need to CAST if your column's type is well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no reason that you need the un-ordered array and your entity is handled by Doctrine you can simply use this code in your controller:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TelnOperatorBundle:Subnumber')->findBy(
    array('numberrange' => $id),
    array('numberrange' => 'asc')
);
```

The first array holds the values for the `WHERE` clause and the second the values for `ORDER BY`.

---

If you want to create an own query - used in a repository for example - simply add:

```
[…]
->where('a.numberrange = :id')
->addOrderBy('a.numberrange', 'desc')
[…]
```

to your query.

---

In both cases the result is sorted by your database. So there's no need to do this on your own.

Comment: I want to add it to the query builder. I think it's more appropriate but should it be after ->where ->setParameter ? an other question : the attribute on which I want to sort is a string of numbers like this '060015000', is that a problem?

Comment: You can place it after `where()` or before it - both notations will work. I don't think that it's a problem to compare those strings.

Comment: Yes I tried this and it works now but the problem is that my attribute on which would be made the sort is a string. is that possible?

Comment: Simply replace the name in `addOrderBy('a.numberrange', 'desc')` with the field you want to use.